# Move jar files within one docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using existing karaf image and unarchiving it while building it with other configurations.(dockerfile)

Now i realized that karaf123.jar file which is in lib folder, it should be in /lib/boot folder.

I tried using COPY but its copying from host, but in my scenario it should just move file from one folder to other within image.

I found following link but no option to copy from container1 to container1
https://medium.com/@gchudnov/copying-data-between-docker-containers-26890935da3f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using a Linux container just add this to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN mv /lib/karaf123.jar /lib/boot/karaf123.jar
```